# Proving Inequality of positive reals

Tags: inequality

$a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are all positive real numbers so that: $a_1+a_2+...+a_n\geq a_1^2+a_2^2+...+a_n^2$ .

Prove that: $a_1^{a_1}a_2^{a_2}...a_n^{a_n} \leq1$ . Find the equality case.

I have tried several inequality rules but none of them are easily applicable to this question since there are powers in this question. Only thing that I achieve is to find "$a_1+a_2+...+a_n \leq n$" . Does anybody have any idea for solving this question?

Comment: @PavanC. That's not it.  If $a_1=1.1,\ a_2=.2,$ then $a_1+a_2=1.3>1.25=a_1^2+a_2^2$

Comment: Looks like an application of the [Weighted AM–GM inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inequality_of_arithmetic_and_geometric_means#Weighted_AM–GM_inequality).

Comment: @MartinR that makes it almost immediate. nice

Comment: @MartinR, Thanks)))

Answer (score 2):

Jensen's inequality implies that
\begin{align*}
\sum\dfrac{a_{k}}{\displaystyle\sum a_{i}}\log a_{k}&\leq\log\sum\dfrac{a_{k}}{\displaystyle\sum a_{i}}a_{k}\\
&=\log\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\sum a_{i}}\sum a_{k}^{2}\\
&\leq\log\dfrac{1}{\displaystyle\sum a_{i}}\sum a_{k}\\
&=0,
\end{align*}
so
\begin{align*}
\log a_{1}^{a_{1}}\cdots a_{n}^{a_{n}}=\sum\log a_{k}^{a_{k}}\leq 0.
\end{align*}

**EDIT:**

The following version of Jensen's inequality is used:
\begin{align*}
\int\log f d\mu\leq\log\left(\int fd\mu\right)
\end{align*}
with $\mu$ the discrete sum measure with the weight $a_{k}/(\sum a_{i})$. Of course, here $f=a_{k}$.

Comment: @Aqua, what about now?

Comment: Very laconic ...